# Docker Configuration on Linux Mint port conflicting with dnsmasq

Tags: linux, docker, dns

I am trying to use a script made my someone else to spin up some docker containers on my Linux Mint 18.1 machine. When I first tried to execute the script (which I unfortunately cannot include) I received an error message that contained the following:

`listen tcp 0.0.0.0:53: bind: address already in use`

When I used netstat to find out what was using the port I discovered that it was `dnsmasq`. I killed the process (knowing it would break my internet, which it did) and I was able to create the containers. So it appears the only issue is the port conflict.

In the guide to the script and in other answers it has been mentioned to add nameserver `127.0.0.1`. I did that but it didn't do anything for me. I have read other answers saying that I cannot change the port that `dnsmasq` uses and I also can't change the port of the docker image. Is there some way I can run both of these?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the docker container HAVE to listen on port 53, you CAN change it by changing the `-p` option of the `docker run` command launching that container.

Comment: Won't this mess up pieces of the program that expect the docker container to be using the specified port?

Comment: Yes, it will. You have to change them to call on the other port you want. Changing `dnsmasq` port will have same effect on application depending on it...